# How to pass numpy array inside of struct to ctypes function?

Tags: python, numpy, ctypes

I'm trying to wrap some third-party code from a library in my Python application. Essentially, the function I would like to call takes a struct as input that houses (among other things) pointers to double arrays. A simplified example would be:

**myfunc.h:**

```
typedef struct mystruct_t {
    int n;
    double *x;
} mystruct_t;

double myfunc(mystruct_t* data);
```

**myfunc.c**:

```
#include "myfunc.h"

double myfunc(mystruct_t* data) {
    double result = 0.;
    for(int i = 0; i < data->n; i++) {
        result += data->x[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

**Makefile**:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -g -Wall -fPIC -lm -std=gnu99

all: libmyfunc.so

m.PHONY : clean

libmyfunc.so: myfunc.o
    gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,$@ -o $@ $^

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $<

clean:
    rm -vf libmyfunc.so *.o
```

I would like to wrap `myfunc` using NumPy, `ctypes.Structure` and `numpy.ctypeslib` so that I can pass NumPy arrays to `myfunc` as attributes of `mystruct_t`. So far I've been trying the following:

**myfunc.py:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import numpy as np
import numpy.ctypeslib as npct
import ctypes
import os

array_1d_double = npct.ndpointer(dtype=np.double, ndim=1, flags='C_CONTIGUOUS')


class MyStruct(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('n', ctypes.c_int16),
        ('x', array_1d_double)
    ]

libmyfunc = npct.load_library('libmyfunc', os.path.dirname(__file__))
libmyfunc.myfunc.restype = ctypes.c_double
libmyfunc.myfunc.argtypes = [
    ctypes.POINTER(MyStruct)
]

x = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0])

mystruct = MyStruct()
mystruct.n = len(x)
mystruct.x = x

res = libmyfunc.myfunc(mystruct)
```

However, this fails with the following error message:

```
$ python myfunc.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./myfunc.py", line 26, in <module>
    mystruct.x = x
TypeError: cannot be converted to pointer
```

How do I define my function signatures correctly so that type conversion can happen? Or do I need to convert `x` somehow before assigning it to `mystruct.x`?

Unfortunately I cannot change the signature of the method I would like to call and I would like to not have to write wrapper C code unless it is absolutely necessary. The other questions and resources that I've found on this only deal with either `ctypes.Structure`s or `numpy.ctypeslib`, but can you make them work together?

I've uploaded my reduced example [as a gist](https://gist.github.com/sseemayer/11218162) so you can use it as a starting point.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove `array_1d_double`. It is not needed.

The struct should be declared like this:

```
class MyStruct(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('n', ctypes.c_int),
        ('x', ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double))
    ]
```

I've changed both types. You had `c_int16`, but the type you used in the C code is `int`. That maps to `c_int`. And likewise for the array, that is `double*`. In ctypes that is `POINTER(ctypes.c_double)`.

The struct should be initialised like this:

```
mystruct = MyStruct()
mystruct.n = len(x)
mystruct.x = npct.as_ctypes(x)
```

With these changes, your code works as intended.

Comment: Ah, stupid mistake about the `c_int`. This works great, thanks for the help!